# Will web crawlers be able to crawl nested sidebar menu for mobile web

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, javascript

[image]

I have a simple question. One clicking on any of the breadcrumbs, an overlay appears as per design. For example, in the above image clicking on Physics will bring up all subjects to choose from and then clicking on a particular subject of choice can lead to chapters and so forth.

If I plan to have a React component for doing so, is there a chance that a webcrawler can look up the whole possible chain? Upside is that I do have whole json for this from API response at once.

If not, what will  be a better alternative?

**Architecture** - This is a server rendered app. The first load will get the entire JSON menu data in one go, build the html with the data and then the further interactions are on client - ReactJs.

Comment: When do you fetch the JSON for this menu and put it into the DOM?  Do you do it when the page loads or when somebody clicks on the button to open the menu?    If it is the latter, Googlebot won't see any links in the menu at all.  Googlebot doesn't click on anything or scroll the page.  All it does is load the page and resources, then scan the DOM for links.

Comment: Right on target. So, I server render the app. It is next.js server render page. So it loads the JSON( API call ) and fills up the initial HTML for menu. I believe, after it is done for that part, it ships it down to the client- ReactJs. Now, rest of the interaction won't be hitting any server calls or page. Is this something that crawlers can recurse?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for Google to Crawl your Sidebar.

You have mentioned that the Breadcrumb contains the Site structure of Main Topics like Physics and then the sub-list will contain the respective chapters of the Subjects.

If your site Structure remains intact despite the Web App being Server side rendered, then You have to use `<nav>` Semantic Tags to make Google Aware about Navigation elements present on the page.

In addition to this, you have to make sure that **Sitemap.xml** also contains the neccessary structure required.

Along with the above two, adding **Schema** elements like Breadcrumbs will further increase the chances of Google to better understand your Website.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb

And last, but not least, you should use proper hierharchy in your **URL structures** to make Google Crawler better understand the Directory Structure of the Website.

I hope, I have answered your question and you will find some or all of this useful.